# UITableView got rendered before data from API returned using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

when I call callapi() function in viewDidLoad(), the println() in callapi prints the posts array with Post objects inside it, however the println() inside the viewDidLoad() function prints an empty array. Also when I build the project I get this error "fatal error: Array index out of range". the println() statement in the tableView function prints an empty array also. It seems the table got rendered before the data from the API arrived how can I solve this?

```
var posts = [Post]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    callapi()
    println(self.posts)
}

func callapi(){
    request(.GET, "url")
    .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
        let json = JSON(data!)
        if let jsonArray = json.array {
            for post in jsonArray {
                var onepost = Post(id:post["id"].stringValue,                    

              title:post["title"].stringValue, 
              author:post["author"].stringValue, 
              post:post["post"].stringValue,   
              created_on:post["created_on"].stringValue, 
              updated_on:post["updated_on"].stringValue)
                self.posts.append(onepost)
                println(self.posts)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
 indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier,
    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    println(self.posts)
    let post = self.posts[indexPath.row]
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLabel!.text = self.posts[indexPath.row].title
    cell.postLabel.text = post.post
    println(self.posts)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method?

Comment: The fact that `posts` is empty in `viewDidLoad` makes perfect sense (because this is populated asynchronously, i.e. later). What doesn't quite make sense is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` shouldn't be called until `numberOfRowsInSection` tells it that there are some rows to show.

Comment: I would, though, move the `reloadData` call outside of the `for` loop. I don't think that's your problem here, but it's inefficient.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for your response, inside tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method, I explicitly set it to return 2, it should have been return self.posts.count why? because i new the length of the array to be 2 already

Comment: now I just changed it to return self.posts.count and it worked!

Comment: what i don't understand is: self.posts.count = 2, which is the length of the array. why is it different from saying return 2?

Comment: It doesn't work because the JSON returns _asynchronously_ (i.e. later). So, when you load the view, the table is loaded before `posts` has anything to show you. When the JSON call is finished, the table is reloaded (because you called `reloadData`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `viewDidLoad` is called, it starts the asynchronous `callapi`, but by the time `viewDidLoad` finishes, `posts` is still empty. But the table view is still going to proceed with its initial load process, even though `posts` hasn't been populated, so you must ensure that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns zero at this point.

Later, `callapi` finishes the Alamofire `GET` request and calls `reloadData`. Only at this point should `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return non-zero value.

Bottom line, make sure that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns the actual number of entries in `posts`, and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now I understand how tableView:numberOfRowsInSection works.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert the reload in viewDidAppear and you are good to go:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you set tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: to return self.posts.count